# Sending cell volume in email title

Tags: excel, vba, email, if-statement, cycle

I need a script that reviews figures from top to bottom of the 3rd column and if it sees 0 and the digit before it is greater than 100 then the value of that digit is sent in the email header. 
The current version of coding sends all the values to the e-mail (the condition does not work).
But  if GoTo is replaced with Msgbox  the script works perfectly...

```
For i = 2 To 100 Step 1
If cells(i, 3) = 0 And cells(i - 1, 3) < 100 Then Exit For
If cells(i, 3) = 0 And cells(i - 1, 3) > 100 Then GoTo email
If cells(i, 3) = 0 And cells(i - 1, 3) > 100 Then Exit For
Next i
email:
Dim olObj_1 As Outlook.Application
Dim mItem_1 As Outlook.MailItem
Set olObj_1 = New Outlook.Application
Set mItem_1 = olObj_1.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With mItem_1
    .To = "xxxx@xxxx.com"
    .Subject = "Figure_one " & cells(i - 1, 3)
    .Send
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Mail()

    Dim i As Long        

    For i = 2 To 100
        If Cells(i, 3) = 0 And Cells(i - 1, 3) > 100 Then
            Dim olObj_1 As Outlook.Application
            Dim mItem_1 As Outlook.MailItem
            Set olObj_1 = New Outlook.Application
            Set mItem_1 = olObj_1.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            With mItem_1
                .To = "xxxx@xxxx.com"
                .Subject = "Figure_one " & Cells(i - 1, 3)
                .Send
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

I'm assuming you only want to send 1 email, otherwise your code should all change.

Comment: Glad it helped, please consider marking this as answer so others can find it @leonardik

Answer (score 1):

i think you could try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim olObj_1 As Outlook.Application
    Dim mItem_1 As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim str As String
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Always select your worksheet name

        For i = 2 To 100

            If .Cells(i, 3).Value = 0 And .Cells(i - 1, 3).Value > 100 Then

                If str = "" Then
                    str = "Figure_one " & .Cells(i - 1, 3).Value
                Else
                    str = str & ", Figure_one " & .Cells(i - 1, 3).Value
                End If

            End With

        Next i

        Set olObj_1 = New Outlook.Application
        Set mItem_1 = olObj_1.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With mItem_1
            .To = "xxxx@xxxx.com"
            .Subject = str
            .Send
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```